# Delete a list of days in different time resolution (minutely data)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this (the timestamp only contains from 9:00 to 20:00)

```
0   2020-05-18 10:18:00
1   2020-05-18 10:19:00
2   2020-05-18 10:20:00
3   2020-05-18 10:21:00
4   2020-05-18 10:22:00
...
?   2020-07-20 12:00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I have a list of several days such (in "incomplete_days") that I want to exclude in df

```
0    2020-05-18
1    2020-05-19
3    2020-05-21
4    2020-05-22
5    2020-05-23
6    2020-05-24

Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I tried simply,

```
df[df['Time'] != incomplete_days]
```

But, the error says

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

1. should I make a timestamp (1 min resolution) with the list of days to exclude
   them in df? If so, how can I make a time with start hour and end hour in given days?
2. Isn't there any way that I don't need to make a timestamp with 1 min resolution?

(I already cut out non-relevant hours from 20:01 to 08:59 and keep hours from 09:00 to 20:00 in the df. I don't want to make again hourly timestamp with the list of days to exclude.
I used the following variables that I used to cut out non-relevant hours )

```
start = time(6)
end = time(20)
```

-----Edited
I did

```
df['Time'].dt.date
```

gives

```
0         2020-05-18
1         2020-05-18
2         2020-05-18
3         2020-05-18
4         2020-05-18
             ...    
110077    2020-08-02
110078    2020-08-02
110079    2020-08-02
110080    2020-08-02
110081    2020-08-02
Name: Time, Length: 69042, dtype: object
```

and

```
list_incomplete=incomplete_days.tolist()
list_incomplete
```

gives

```
[Timestamp('2020-05-18 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-19 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-21 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-23 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-25 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-27 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-28 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-05-31 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-06-10 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-05 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00')]
```

When I do

```
df.drop([df['Time'].dt.date not in incomplete_days],inplace=True)
```

I get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I see it is very close but something got wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two dataframes `df` and `df1` with their columns in datetime format:

`df`

```
    Date
0   2020-05-18 10:18:00
1   2020-05-18 10:19:00
2   2020-05-18 10:20:00
3   2020-05-18 10:21:00
4   2020-05-18 10:22:00
5   2020-07-20 12:00:00
```

`df1`

```
    incomplete_days
0   2020-05-18
1   2020-05-19
3   2020-05-21
4   2020-05-22
5   2020-05-23
6   2020-05-24
```

You can use boolean indexing and convert both columns to strings with same format for comparison. Use `~` with `isin` (which effectively is "not in") rather than `!=`. You cannot use `!=` to compare rows to an entire series, so your current method is a syntax error. Converting the format within the boolean indexing `[]` will maintain the initial format of your dataframe and won't change from a date to a string.

```
df = df[~(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').isin(df1['incomplete_days'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))]

Out[38]: 
Date
5 2020-07-20 12:00:00
```

Comment: I am sorry for causing a confusion. It was a little mistake of mine. It works perfect! Thanks a lot, David!